# creating button in visual studio that can reset itself

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, click

Im looking into writing a code that leads to change of the button color setting if the button is clicked and reset it if its clicked for a second time. 
Does any one have any idea how to do this?
Here is my initial code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   button1.Text = "1";
   button1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
   button1.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: Winforms..? wpf..?

Comment: Sounds like you want a very simple Finite State Machine.

Comment: Do you want to have a toggle button?

Answer (score 1):

you can do a toggle function like so...

```
public bool ButtonIsClicked = false;

public void ToggleControls()
{
  ButtonIsClicked = !ButtonIsClicked;

  if(ButtonIsClicked)
  {
    //new button color
  }
  else
  {
    //old button color
  }
}
```

Comment: Minor niggle: `ButtonIsClicked` probably should be `private`. Been a while since I've done any C#. Does it support `static` local variable yet?

Comment: Yes, static works as well.

`private static bool ButtonIsClicked` would be fine too.

Comment: On further thought it doesn't. Removes the ability to have multiple instances of the button. Mostly just interested in knowing if it exists.

Comment: Ah yeah I suppose you've got a point there. Depends on how many instances of the button they need I guess.

Comment: What I was aiming at was something that works in C and C++ for free functions: Code looks like `void ToggleControls(){ static bool ButtonIsClicked = false; if(ButtonIsClicked) ... }`. Useful in that it scopes the visibility of the variable as local to the function, but has permanence between calls.

Comment: Thanks emsimpson92! However, this doesnt work for me, Do you type this in the form.cs file or the form.designer.cs?

Comment: Put it in the form.cs file, and be sure to call `ToggleControls()` in your button_click event handler. Don't forget to call `Refresh()` on your button as well once you change its color.

Comment: please forgive my low level of knowledge but do you men something like this:        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            public bool ButtonIsClicked = false;

        public void ToggleControls()
        {
            ButtonIsClicked = !ButtonIsClicked;

            if (ButtonIsClicked)
            {
                //blah
            }
            else
            {
                // blah
            }
        }
    }

Comment: What you're doing there is declaring the variable and function. You want to do that outside of your other function declaration. All you have to do after that is add this line into your `button1_Click()` function: `ToggleControls();` Then every time a user clicks the button, the color will toggle.

Comment: would that work for 3 state situation? I want to click (button text from empty to 0), another click (button text from 0 to 1), and the next click (button text from 1 to empty) and this could be done in multiple rounds

Comment: No, the method I suggested is a binary toggle only. You might want to instead implement a counter to keep track of how many times it has been clicked, then run an if/else or switch statement to determine your button color.